# Why it is allowable to create Thread instance with NON Runnable argument?

Tags: java, multithreading, initialization, functional-interface

I encountered code like this(I simplidied it a bit) in the article:

```
public class Main {


    static class A {        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(A::new).start();
    }
}
```

I surprised about that code because from my point if view it must produce compile time error because `Thread` constructor accepts `Runnable` but `A` doesn't have methid `run`  but it compiles  and even starts without any errors/exceptions. I checked it on my PC in several variations and it works anyway.

So I have following questions:

Why there no compilation errors?
Which method executes instead of run method?

Comment: See the dupe as the key point here is "If the body of a lambda is a statement expression (that is, an expression that would be allowed to stand alone as a statement), it is compatible with a void-producing function type; **any result is simply discarded**." same applies in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) is a [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) which can also be represented in lambda expression as in your case:

```
new Thread(() -> new A())
```

which is nothing but a similar representation of method-reference

```
A::new
```

that in your code is equivalent to

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new A(); // just creating an instance of 'A' for every call to 'run'
    }
}
```